# Find the rule : triplet number into Positive Integer

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers, number-theory

These are triplets of numbers into positive integers:

```
[0,0,0] => 0
[1,0,0] => 1
[1,1,0] => 2
[1,1,1] => 3
[2,0,0] => 4
[0,2,0] => 5
[1,2,0] => 6
[1,2,1] => 7
[1,1,2] => 8
[2,2,0] => 9
[3,1,0] => 10
...
[3,2,1] => 15
...
[3,3,3] => 36
[4,4,4] => 66
[5,5,5] => 105
[6,6,6] => 153
```

> $[10,10,10]$ => $?$

Note :

- I have checked that every integer from $0$ to $10^6$ can be written into a triplet (so, I believe it's true for every integer);
- Usually, $[a,b,c] ≠ [b,c,a] ≠ [c,b,a]$;
- An integer can have some triplet, but not vice versa. Example [2,2,0] = [3,0,0] => 9.

Addition :

I added more examples, so I hope the information is enough now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We plainly don't have enough information here, but here is a class of solutions.

> [a,b,c] maps to f(a)+g(b)+h(c) where f,g,h are functions with the following properties:
>  f(0)=0, f(1)=1, f(2)=4, f(3)=9 (so there's an obvious guess for f)
>  g(0)=0, g(1)=1, g(2)=5
>  h(0)=0, h(1)=1, h(2)=6
>  every nonnegative integer has a representation as f+g+h

So it's clear enough that

> we can find plenty of f,g,h having these properties (I can give several if requested)

but the challenge is

> to find "nice" ones (it seems like g,h "want" to grow faster than the square numbers which introduces a little difficulty in making sure every nonnegative integer is represented).

The obvious guess is

> f = square numbers, g = pentagonal numbers, h = hexagonal numbers

and my numerical expectation suggests that this probably works. I haven't attempted to find a proof (either someone else's or my own); it might be difficult to prove if true.

Anyway, the question asked for [10,10,10]. With the representation above that would yield

> $10^2 + \frac{1}{2}10(3\cdot10-1) + 10(2\cdot10-1)=100+145+190=435$.

Comment: I have add some more example, so I hope the information are enaugh now. And your guess is right, so just answer what is [10,10,10]

Comment: Done (at about the same time as you were writing that comment).